# What are the links those are generated on some specific Google Search result?

Tags: google-search

Today I searched "Hadoop Training" on Google and I found the the result as following screen-shot image link.

[image]

Here I found a search result, where there are 4 link at the bottom of a search result. (I have marked those with green color square box)

So I want to know:

1. Are those 4 link has been mentioned using schema.org markup inside the search result page?
2. Or, are those Google Sitelinks?

Could anyone help me to find out what are those 4 links and how those can be specified inside Google search?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question but one about web site administration and seo; both of which are off topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those links are a special feature of Google called [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en), and **you don't have control over them**, you just can opt to remove a sitelink but you can't decide which ones Google shows.

> Our systems analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're looking for.

The most common scenario is that they are being displayed with sublinks and their respective description excerpt, as shown in the following image:

[image: sitelinks]

What you are seeing for the webpage you sent, is a special view of this feature, i.e., a subset of the sublinks that shows only the sitelinks headers:

[image]

Look how each subheader corresponds to the bigger picture.

What could help to get those sitelinks is to have a clear structure and a sitemap, but at the end, all depends on the big G.

Comment: Thank us so much marcanuy for this answer. It would really help me.